# Noninteracting particles in Griffith QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, fermions

In [Griffth's QM text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131118927), he says in Section 5.1,

> Suppose we have two noninteracting particles, both of mass $m$, in the infinite square well (Section 2.2). The one particle states are,
>   $$
> \psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right),\quad E_n=n^2K
> $$
>   (where $K=\pi^2\hbar^2/2ma$). If the particles are *distinguishable*, the composite wave functions are simple products:
>   $$
> \psi_{n_1n_2}\left(x_1,\,x_2\right)=\psi_{n_1}\left(x_1\right)\psi_{n_2}\left(x_2\right),\quad E_n=\left(n_1^2+n_2^2\right)K.
> $$
>   ...if the particles are identical *fermions*, there is *no* state with energy $2K$; the ground state is
>   $$
> \frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}\left[\sin\left(\pi x_1/a\right)\sin\left(2\pi x_2/a\right)-\sin\left(2\pi x_1/a\right)\sin\left(\pi x_2/a\right)\right],
> $$
>   and its energy is $5K$.

Griffith's says that there is no state of energy $2K$ for two fermions, but I wonder why author doesn't consider about spin. If two fermion have different spin (singlet state), they don't violate Pauli's exclusion principle and can have energy $2K$. Why am I wrong?

Comment: If he had meant for the particles to have spin, don't you think he would have said so?

Comment: Do you mean I can ignore spin in this example?

Answer (score 1):

In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, particles do not naturally have spin$^\dagger$ - you have to add that in by hand.  In this example, Griffiths does not do this, so you should naturally take the particles to be spin-less.

In fact, he actually gives the single particle states to be
$$\psi_n = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right)$$

If the particles had spin 1/2, for example, the single particle states would be

$$\psi_{n\alpha\beta}= \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right) \otimes \pmatrix{\alpha \\ \beta}$$

where $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$.

---

As DanielC points out in his comment, this is not necessarily true.  The "typical procedure" for working in nonrelativistic QM involves starting from a chosen (separable) Hilbert space and some relevant Hamiltonian.  If we take this view, then we could (for instance) choose our Hilbert space to be whatever we wanted - and given two Hilbert spaces $\mathcal H_1$ and $\mathcal H_2$, we could form a new Hilbert space given by $\mathcal H_1 \otimes \mathcal H_2$.

If we want to describe a particle which exists in $3D$ space, a typical choice for the Hilbert space (in accordance with Born's statistical interpretation) is $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$.  If the particle has some kind of intrinsic structure, then we could reflect that by appending some "ancillary" space to yield a total Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R^3) \otimes \mathcal H_{anc}$.  However, there is no immediately apparent reason why we *have* to do this, nor is there an immediately obvious choice of $\mathcal H_{anc}$ for any given system.

However, there is alternative approach.  If we declare the Galilei group to be the kinematical symmetry group of the system, a natural move would be to classify its irreducible representations.  In doing so, we find that a generic irreducible representation of the Galilei group lives in the space $L^2(\mathbb R^3) \otimes \mathcal C^{2s+1}$ for some integer or half-integer $s$ - from this point of view, spin arises just as naturally as it does in QFT (where particles are seen as the irreducible representations of the Poincare group).

Comment: In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, particles naturally have spin. Stop spreading this incorrect knowledge.

Comment: @DanielC Perhaps you could educate me on this issue, then.

Comment: I couldn't, but Jean-Marc Levy-Leblond can: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1724319

Comment: @DanielC Particles naturally have spin if, by *particle*, you mean *irreducible representation of the Galilei group*.  This is not the typical formulation of non-relativistic QM (certainly, it is not the path that Griffiths takes), in which one *starts* from a Hilbert space and a choice of Hamiltonian operator.

Comment: Ultimately it's a choice of what you consider to be fundamental.  If you take the latter approach and start from a Hamiltonian which acts on $L^2(\mathbb R)$, then you are implicitly dealing with a spinless particle. OTOH if you start from a Hamiltonian which acts on $L^2(\mathbb R) \otimes \mathbb C^2$, then you are implicitly dealing with a particle with spin 1/2.  There is no *a priori* reason to choose one over the other from this point of view, and it is in this sense that I mean that spin does not arise naturally.

Comment: Your point is valuable and worth considering.  Nonrelativistic QM is often motivated by classical analogy, whereas QFT is usually motivated by the imposition of symmetry groups; the "natural" rise of spin in relativistic QM is not due to relativistic effects, but rather to the fundamental difference in approach.  If we apply the same procedure to nonrelativistic QM, then spin arises just as naturally - it's just that this not the typical lens through which QM is developed.  Perhaps it should be.  Regardless, I've edited my answer.